# Modificar campo input cuando el usuario interactue con ellos para valid e invalid

Tags: html5, input

Estoy trabajando en un formulario y estoy controlando sus patrones con los pattern de html5 para mas tarde poner js, acabo de crear las clases valid e invalid, y el problema es que se checkean al renderizar la página, como le quito esa propiedad, lo suyo es que solo cambien a valid o invalid cuando el usuario escriba o de al submit del formulario, alguna idea? necesito que aparezcan con los estilos de la web y solo cambies cuando el usuario interactue con el formulario.

Comment: ¿Y el código para un ejemplo mínimo y verificable?

Comment: Hola, he publicado la solución explicandolo mejor abajo, gracias

Answer (score 0):

He estado buscando y he visto que si le doy estilos a los input:valid e input:invalid lógicamente cuando se pinta el formulario ya se formatean en validos e inválidos y esto al usuario lo puede desorientar.
He trabajado sobre los los input:invalid:focus e input:valid:focus, así no se formatean hasta que el usuario interactúa con el formulario.

```
input:invalid:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid var(--color-red);
    background-color: rgb(255, 202, 202);
}

input:valid:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid var(--color-green);
    background-color: rgb(214, 253, 214);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por hacerlo sencillo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .content {
            border-radius: 3px;
            border       : 1px solid grey;
            margin       : 5rem auto;
            padding      : 1rem;
        }
        label {
            display       : flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin-bottom : 1rem;
        }

        input:invalid {
            border-color: red;
        }
        input:valid {
            border-color: initial;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <form>
            <label>
                <span>Email:</span>
                <input type="email" name="email">
            </label>

            <label>
                <span>Password:</span>
                <input type="password" name="pw" minlength="8">
            </label>
            

            <button type="submit">Entrar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sólo aparece el borde de los *inputs* en rojo, una vez perdido el foco si su contenido no cumple las reglas: para el input de tipo *email* un email válido. Para input de tipo *password* una longitud mínima de 8 caracteres.

Más info sobre formularios HTML5: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/HTML/HTML5/Forms_in_HTML5